# GoogleAppsScriptのMailApp.sendEmailで、メールが届くアカウントと届かないアカウントがある

Tags: api, google-apps-script, sendmail

MailApp.sendEmailを用いて、Googleフォームからスプレッドシートに入力された回答を、回答されたことをトリガーにエイリアス含む複数メールアドレスへメール送信しています。

> var to = "alias01@sample.co.jp,alias02@sample.co.jp,個人アカウント@sample.co.jp";

同じアンケートフォーム回答でもメールが届く場合と届かない場合があるのですが、
どのようなことが原因なのでしょうか。

少なくとも3/18頃から発生していますが、現在も継続しています。
APIの障害か否かは4/10までしか遡って確認できないため、
[障害なのか仕様変更なのか過去の履歴を調査している](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list?can=1&q=sendmail&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner&cells=tiles)ところです。

どのようなことが原因なのか、
アドバイスいただけるとありがたいです。

コードは下記になります。

```
function send( e ) {
    var subject = "文字列 ";
    var header
        = "文字列 \n\n";
    var footer
        = "\n";
    var to = "mail1@sample.co.jp,mail2@sample.co.jp,mail3@sample.co.jp";
    var options = {};

    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var rows = sh.getLastRow();
    var cols = sh.getLastColumn();
    var rg = sh.getDataRange();

    try {
        body = header;

        for (var i = 1; i <= cols; i++ ) {
            var col_name  = rg.getCell(1, i).getValue();
            var col_value = rg.getCell(rows, i).getValue();

            body += "[ "+col_name+" ]\n";
            body += col_value + "\n\n";
        }

        body += footer;

        MailApp.sendEmail(to, subject, body, options);
    } catch(e) {
        MailApp.sendEmail(to, subject + " - Google フォーム エラー", e.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: 「届くアカウントと届かないアカウントがある(同じメールを送っているのに)」なのか、「メールが届く場合と届かない場合がある(同じアカウントなのに)」のかどちらでしょうか？タイトルと質問内容が相反しており、どちらに回答すれば良いのか困ります。なお、容量制限があることはご存じですか？ https://script.google.com/dashboard の容量制限タブ

Comment: ご確認ありがとうございます！
タイトルと質問に差異があってわかりづらくて失礼いたしました・・・

今回起きているのは
「届くアカウントと届かないアカウントがある(同じメールを送っているのに)」
となります。

>容量制限があることはご存じですか？
はい、Gmailのアカウント毎容量制限のことですよね。届かないアカウントは容量制限（私達の環境では30GBです）を超えていませんでした

他にご指摘あればコメントいただけますとありがたいです！
どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Comment: ああ、スミマセン。制限というのは、`1 日あたりのメール受信者 100 個/日` の方です。100人以上に送っているのではないかと思いまして。